# Loading external file from Karma/Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, json, intellij-idea, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to accomplish a Jasmine test (using Karma and IntelliJ 13) to validate JSON files. Ideally, my test would simply load a JSON file into a data object, then let me parse through to check for valid formatting and data. I don't need to validate functions before or after, nor do I need to test against a server.

My basic setup is like this:

```
it("should load an external file", function(){
var asyncCallComplete, result,
            _this = this;
        // asyncCallComplete is set to true when the ajax call is complete
        asyncCallComplete = false;

        // result stores the result of the successful ajax call
        result = null;

        // SECTION 1 - call asynchronous function
        runs(function() {
            return $.ajax('/test/config.json', {
                type: 'GET',
                success: function(data) {
                    asyncCallComplete = true;
                    result = data;
                },
                error: function() {
                    asyncCallComplete = true;
                }
            });
        });

        // SECTION 2 - wait for the asynchronous call to complete
        waitsFor(function() {
            return asyncCallComplete !== false;
        }, "async to complete");

        // SECTION 3 - perform tests
        return runs(function() {
            return expect(result).not.toBeNull();
        });
}
```

The problem is that no matter what path I use, I get a 404 error and the file won't load. I've tried loading an external JSON result from a remote server using this test service:

http://date.jsontest.com/

And this works.

My test file is named /test/mySpec.js and my karma.conf.js file is on the root. I have moved around the JSON file to all of these locations with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER:**

Per the answer below, I added this to my karma.conf.js:

```
// fixtures
{ pattern: 'test/*.json',
    watched: true,
    served:  true,
    included: false
}
```

Then, I wrote my test this way:

```
    var json:any;
    it("should load a fixture", function () {
        jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "base/test/"
        var f = readFixtures("registration.json");
        json = JSON.parse(f);
        expect(json).toBeDefined();

    })

    it("should have a title", function () {
        expect(json.title).toNotBe(null);
    })
    etc...
```

And it passes.

Comment: instead of reading in fixtures you can now say  jasmine.getJSONFixtures().fixturesPath='base/test/apiMocks';  var data = getJSONFixture('test.json');

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Are you serving the JSON file via karma.config.js?

You can serve JSON files via fixture:

```
files: [
      // angular 
      'angular.min.js',
      'angular-route.js',
      'angular-mocks.js',

      // jasmine jquery helper
     'jquery-1.10.2.min.js',
     'jasmine-jquery.js',

      //  app
      '../../public/js/app.js',

      // tests
      '*-spec.js',

      // JSON fixture
      { pattern:  '/test/*.json',
        watched:  true,
        served:   true,
        included: false }
    ],
```

Comment: Thanks, jsplaine. I have been trying this as well. For some reason, today it worked, although I'm not sure what I did differently besides got some sleep. :-)

Comment: Will it work for a non json file as well. Say a text file or .xlsx file ?

Comment: I am trying this very solution, but I get weird 404 errors, the file I want to server up is validConfig.json and I get 404 related to not finding file validConfigon.js. not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 8):

Serving JSON via the fixture is the easiest but because of our setup we couldn't do that easily so I wrote an alternative helper function:

### Install

`bower install karma-read-json`

### Usage

1. Put karma-read-json.js in your Karma files, Example:

   ```
   files = [
   ...
   'bower_components/karma-read-json/karma-read-json.js',
   ...
   ]
   ```
2. Make sure your JSON is being served by Karma, Example:

   ```
   files = [
   ...
   {pattern: 'json/**/*.json', included: false},
   ...
   ]
   ```
3. Use the `readJSON` function in your tests. Example:

   ```
   var valid_respond = readJSON('json/foobar.json');
   $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).respond(valid_respond);
   ```

Comment: I have installed your package and tried without success, it gave me a 404, file not found error (the .json file). How do you make it work?

Comment: I'm new to this Karma stuff so my guess is your json is file is not at the path you entered. The package adds `/base/` to all paths. See: https://github.com/pizzapanther/Karma-Read-JSON/blob/master/karma-read-json.js#L2

Make sure the URL your json is serving at is correct.

Comment: I have made some changes on your code so the `/base/` url becomes generic. I also added a closure to the main function. 
Would you like me to PR the changes so you can review them? (For my app, I think more work is still required to make this work). Regards

Comment: Cool thanks for the help, left some comments on the PR. I'd like to make it more generic but also leave `/base/` as the default since that is the Karma default.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to load a HTML file and want to avoid using *jasmine-jquery*, you may take advantage of the *karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor*.

In your *karma.conf.js* :

```
// generate js files from html templates
preprocessors: {
    'resources/*.html': 'ng-html2js'
},

files: [
    ...
    'resources/*.html'
],

plugins: [
    ...
    'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
],
```

In your jasmine spec :

```
beforeEach(module('resources/fragment.html'));

var $templateCache;
beforeEach(inject(function (_$templateCache_) {
    $templateCache = _$templateCache_;
}));

describe('some test', function () {
    it('should do something', function () {
        // --> load the fragment.html content from the template cache <--
        var fragment = $templateCache.get('resources/fragment.html');
        expect(fragment).toBe(...);
    });
});
```

Comment: Using `$templateCache` should be fine without a pre-processor -- why do you use one?

Comment: `module` is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply requiring the json file and storing it as a global variable in your test?

I'm developing an Angular2 project right now (using the Angular CLI), and with this setup it works:

`// On the very beginning of the file
let mockConfig = require('./test/config.json');`