# Karma: uncaught ReferenceError $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, karma-runner

I have seen many other answers on this site but none of them worked for me.

The problem: I need to load jQuery with an URL, not with a local path; and I think I can't add thoose to "files" on karma.conf.js.

Everything seems to be fine, but when I try to use karma to test it, it returns: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

The order of the scripts is fine in the two .html we use.

Comment: Can you delay the test execution? in protractor you'd do something like `ptor.sleep(2000)` before/in your test blocks

Comment: I don't know how to do it, or what is protractor. Sorry, this is an assignment in the Uni, and we aren't really familiar with this tools.

Comment: We use Karma and Gulp for this (with Mocha and Chai, if that matters)

Comment: I believe you can just add the external url to the `files` block in your `karma.config.js` (unsure) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20938320/loading-external-file-from-karma-jasmine-test

Comment: Working: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70940235/7186739

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simple include the jQuery path in the `karma.conf.js` (as for Karma 0.12 at least):

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    files: [
      'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'
      ...
    ],

    ...
  });
};
```

I've tested it yesterday because I needed a similar thing for AngularJS.

Comment: AFAIK the format of the karma config file in the version 1.0 is stil the same as the one described in this answer: http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html