# How can I load binary files in a Jasmine/Karma test?

Tags: unit-testing, webpack, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular project that parses binary files from user input. This makes unit testing difficult. I'd like to be able to include these files in my Jasmine/Karma tests which are run in a browser.

I have found that I am able to use [Karma's `files` property](https://karma-runner.github.io/6.4/config/files.html) to get these files included into Karma so they can be loaded.

**karma.conf.js**

```js
files: [
  {
    pattern: "sample-files/*.sbsong",
    watched: false,
    served: true,
    included: false,
  },
],
```

Now I try to load this file into a test like this

```js
it('should parse a binary file', () =>{
  const file  = require('/sample-files/song1.sbsong');
  
  const parsedFile = parser(file);
  expect(parsedFile).toEqual('foo');
});
```

This generates an error, however it also confirms that the file path is correct and it sees the file

```txt
./sample-files/song1.sbsong:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

This feels like it's so close, but how can I get karma or webpack to just give me the data of this file so I can pass it on to my parser for a unit test? Currently it seems to be trying to load these files as a javascript module, but I just want to get the raw file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the opensource project [Koia.io](https://github.com/centeractive/koia), I load an [Excel file](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/shared/services/reader/excel/test.xlsx) to be used in a Jasmine unit test defined inside [`excel-reader.spec.ts`](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/shared/services/reader/excel/excel-reader.spec.ts).

To do so, I had to define the file inside [karma.conf.js](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/karma.conf.js) as follows:

```
files: [
   ...  
   { 
     pattern: 'src/app/shared/services/reader/excel/test.xlsx', 
     included: false, 
     watched: false, 
     served: true 
   }
]
```

The relevant function in [`excel-reader.spec.ts`](https://github.com/centeractive/koia/blob/master/src/app/shared/services/reader/excel/excel-reader.spec.ts) is `loadExcelFile`.

```
async function loadExcelFile(): Promise<File> {
  const response = await fetch(EXCEL_FILE_URL);
  const blob = await response.blob();
  return new File([blob], 'test.xlsx');
}
```

I think, a similar approach should also work in your case. If you don't need a file, simply let the function return the [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

Comment: Amazing, thank you!  I knew it had to be possible and this makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: Just finished rewriting a lot of tests that relied on mock files with the file content copied as string variables. This greatly simplifies things, especially for binary files where I wasn't able to copy the contents as a string